# TableView updates on simulator but not on phone

Tags: iphone, xcode, tableview, simulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [tableview will not update on phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127944/tableview-will-not-update-on-phone)

I asked this before, but didnt attach code and never got an answer and am getting desperate lol.
If this is a repost, I apologize, but I have been scouring the net and cant seem to find anything that works. I have a list of workouts that I display in a tableview that are gathered in plists in the bundle. There is a also a separate tab that I have that allows a user to build their own workouts and save them in the documents folder plist file. Once they are saved, they are added to the table view. In the simulator, everyuhting works fine. But on the actual device, it is not updated unless I close the program for an extended period of time, reload the program from xcode, or turn the phone off. I have tried adding [[self tableview] reload] to "viewDidLoad", "viewWillappear", and "viewDidAppear" and none of them work. Once again, the file is saved, the updating does work in the simulator, and it doesn't update in the phone right away. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Edit: i know it is a long piece of code, but should be straight forward (hopefully lol)

```
#import "BIDWODList.h"
#import "BIDWODDetails.h"

#define kFileName   @"SavedDFWorkouts.plist"

@interface BIDWODList ()

@end

@implementation BIDWODList
@synthesize names;
@synthesize savedNames;
@synthesize keys;
@synthesize details;
@synthesize wodType;
@synthesize benchmarkGirls;
@synthesize theNewGirls;    
@synthesize heroes;
@synthesize savedDFGWorkouts;
@synthesize chosenWOD;
@synthesize chosenDetails;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *buildBenchmarkGirls = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *buildTheNewGirls = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *buildHeroes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSURL *plistURL = [bundle URLForResource:@"CrossfitWOD" withExtension:@"plist"];
    //put the contents of the plist into a NSDictionary, and then into names instance variable
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:plistURL];
    self.names = dictionary;
    //take all the keys in the dictionary and make an array out of those key names
    self.keys = [self.names allKeys];

    for (NSString *nameCheck in keys){
        self.details = [names valueForKey:nameCheck];
        if ([[self.details valueForKey:@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"The Benchmark Girls"]) {
            [buildBenchmarkGirls addObject:nameCheck];
        }else if ([[self.details valueForKey:@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"The New Girls"]) {
            [buildTheNewGirls addObject:nameCheck];
        }else {
            [buildHeroes addObject:nameCheck];
        }
    }

    NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
    NSMutableDictionary *savedWorkout = [[NSMutableDictionary         alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    self.savedNames = savedWorkout;
    self.savedDFGWorkouts = [[savedWorkout allKeys]     sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    self.benchmarkGirls = [buildBenchmarkGirls sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    self.theNewGirls = [buildTheNewGirls sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    self.heroes = [buildHeroes sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
//[[self tableView] reloadData];  //reloads the data in case a DFG workout was saved

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.names = nil;
    self.keys = nil;
    self.benchmarkGirls = nil;
    self.theNewGirls = nil;;
    self.heroes = nil;
    self.details = nil;
```

}

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (NSString *)dataFilePath {
    NSArray *paths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kFileName];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 4;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (section == 0) {
        return [benchmarkGirls count];
    }else if (section == 1){
        return [theNewGirls count];
    }else if (section == 2){
        return [heroes count];
    }else{
        return [savedDFGWorkouts count];
    }

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    static NSString *SectionsTableIdentifier = @"SectionsTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SectionsTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SectionsTableIdentifier];
    }

    if (section == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [benchmarkGirls objectAtIndex:row];
    }else if (section == 1) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [theNewGirls objectAtIndex:row];
    }else if (section == 2) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [heroes objectAtIndex:row];
    }else{
        cell.textLabel.text = [savedDFGWorkouts objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return @" The Benchmark Girls";
    }else if (section == 1){
        return @"The New Girls";
    }else if (section ==2){
        return @"The Heroes";
    }else{
        return @"Saved DFG Workouts";
    }
}



#pragma mark - Table view delegate


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    BIDWODDetails *destination = segue.destinationViewController;

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
if (section == 0) {
    self.chosenWOD = [self.benchmarkGirls objectAtIndex:row];
    self.chosenDetails = [names objectForKey:chosenWOD];
}else if (section == 1) {
    self.chosenWOD = [self.theNewGirls objectAtIndex:row];
    self.chosenDetails = [names objectForKey:chosenWOD];
}else if (section ==2) {
    self.chosenWOD = [self.heroes objectAtIndex:row];
    self.chosenDetails = [names objectForKey:chosenWOD];
}else {
    self.chosenWOD = [self.savedDFGWorkouts objectAtIndex:row];
    self.chosenDetails = [savedNames objectForKey:chosenWOD];
}//end if

//self.chosenDetails = [names objectForKey:chosenWOD];
//[destination setValue:chosenWOD forKey:@"chosenWOD"];
//[destination setValue:chosenDetails forKey:@"chosenDetails"];
destination.chosenWOD = self.chosenWOD;
destination.chosenDetails = self.chosenDetails;
}

@end
```

Comment: Update your older post: [tableview will not update on phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127944/tableview-will-not-update-on-phone) don't start a new one.

Comment: I updated your original post with some suggestions.